# vim fold behavior like foldmethod=marker but make the fold exclude its marker lines?

Tags: vim

I would like to define a fold expression in vim that behaves like
foldmethod=marker except that I would like each fold to exclude
its delimiting marker lines, instead of including them.
For example, given the file:

```
a 
{{{
    b
    {{{
        c
    }}}
    d
    {{{
    }}}
    e
}}}
f
```

The fold levels produced by foldmethod=marker are:

```
0 a 
1 {{{
1     b 
2     {{{
2         c
2     }}}
1     d 
2     {{{
2     }}}
1     e 
1 }}}
0 f
```

But I would like them to be this instead:

```
0 a 
0 {{{
1     b 
1     {{{
2         c
1     }}}
1     d 
1     {{{
1     }}}
1     e 
0 }}}
0 f
```

Is there a way?

Comment: If your files are indented as your examples are, you can try folding by indentation... http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Folding_for_plain_text_files_based_on_indentation

Comment: @f41lurizer they're not necessarily indented like that.